# android servlet jsp communication

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have an android application that sends data to a server every 10 seconds. the server processes the data received *and has to display that on a jsp page. for every set of data received from the client, the jsp in the server has to be refreshed.*

i am unable to accomplish the italicized part. i save the processed data by using `request.setAttribute()` and when i use the request dispatcher to call the jsp. instead of opening the page, the server sends the jsp page code back to client. 
could someone please tell me what is the mistake i am doing.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this behavior is correct. The client must decide what to do with the response. If you think about it in a client/server application where the client is a browser. The browser sends the request to the server. The server handles the request and reports back to the browser with a response. The browser takes the response and displays it.

Comment: But how I do make the server open a new page and send its response there.